# How do Miles Morales's shoes fit after he gets bitten?

Tags: marvel, spider-man, spider-man-into-the-spider-verse

In *Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse*, Miles experiences a significant growth spurt after being bitten, which means that his pants no longer fit him (see around 14:05).  However, he's shown wearing his shoes shortly after that, and they presumably still fit him (see around 14:17).

How is this possible?

(I realize that this is a definitely a nitpick and not an important aspect of the movie, but I noticed it while rewatching *Spider-Verse* today and was curious enough to type out this question.  Also, I haven't read any of the Miles Morales comics, but feel free to reference them in your answer if they're relevant.)

Comment: “How is this possible?” Turns out his feet didn't grow.

Comment: According to [Foot Length As A Marker of Pubertal Onset - S MITRA, M SAMANTA, M SARKAR AND S CHATTERJEE](http://medind.nic.in/ibv/t11/i7/ibvt11i7p549.pdf) approximately 5% of children entering puberty experience no/negligible foot growth. That being said, a heavy growth spurt is usually cocomitant with statistically significant foot growth.

Comment: Could be that his shoes were a little too big for him before his growth spurt. The question isn't so much "how is it possible," since it's entirely possible for completely mundane reasons. It's more like "has the specific reason ever been mentioned."

Comment: Yeah, my feet are a half-size, and (in the UK at least) half sizes aren't always available in all styles so often I'll have to buy the next whole size up. My feet could easily grow a half size and my shoes would still fit. They could probably grow a full size and, while the shoes wouldn't "fit" in that they'd be very uncomfortable, I dare say I'd still be able to squeeze into them until I got some replacements.

Comment: (also, never tying his laces probably gives him more room to grow... it's a choice XD)